# Error - ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression but works when I remove f.film_no AS "Film Number"

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

```
SELECT  f.title AS "Film Title",f.film_no AS "Film Number", MIN(c.fee) AS "Lowest Contract Cost"
FROM film f, contract c
WHERE f.film_no = c.film_no
GROUP BY f.title
HAVING MIN(fee) > 7000000;
```

When I run it it comes out with the error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression but when I remove 'f.film_no AS "Film Number" it then works?

This one doesn't work at all

```
SELECT d.firstnames AS "First Name", COUNT(f.title) AS "Number of Films"
FROM director d, film f
WHERE d.director_id = f.director_id
GROUP BY d.surname
HAVING COUNT(f.title) > 1;
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the error obvious? You have an unaggregated column in the `SELECT` that is not in the `GROUP BY`.  So you can either use an aggregation function or include it.

Also, NEVER use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

So:

```
SELECT f.title AS "Film Title", f.film_no AS "Film Number",
       MIN(c.fee) AS "Lowest Contract Cost"
FROM film f JOIN
     contract c
     ON f.film_no = c.film_no
GROUP BY f.title, f.film_no
HAVING MIN(fee) > 7000000;
```

Comment: @Jackawan . . . Learn to use `JOIN`!  Don't ever use commas in the `FROM` clause.